# Icon font characters are different sizes but have exactly the same CSS

Tags: html, css, icons, webfonts

I'm trying to create different font "icons" with CSS but I'm having some weird issue as I scale them up. They seem to be adjusting to different ratios and I'm not sure why. When I created my "largest" style it looked different (Proportionally) than the others, so I reverted it back to the previous size to compare and it had the same issue even though the CSS was virtually identical (The only difference was a class name).

Here is the code:

http://codepen.io/ajrdesign/pen/hdtEC

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Found it. For some reason font-awesome has a .icon-large class built in that I didn't know about. I changed the large setting and it fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. For some reason font-awesome has a .icon-large class built in that I didn't know about. I changed the large setting and it fixed everything.

I had to dig around in the inspector comparing the two elements down to the very last selector to find it.